# Isekai manga where the hero moves to another world and encounters a girl from his world that turns out to be his dad

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

I remember a manga where the hero moves to another world. He encounters a girl who works in a restaurant whom he suspects is from his world. The hero is surprised by the food there. He approaches her and discovers that she is his father (the father is in the body of the girl).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is [*Isekai Shokudou*](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=141703). I see some points identical to this.
It sounds like Ep 12 of *Isekai Shokudou* (I haven't read the manga).

- There are 4 heroes who defeat the Devil King. But 1 of them got isekaied in order to defeat the devil.
- 1 of them enters the restaurant (which connects two worlds every Saturday).
- He meets the owner of the restaurant (son of the female Hero Koyomi who got transported 50+ years ago).
- There is 1 girl working there and 1 dragon lady both from the same world (like the hero) who come to do maid job every Saturday.
- The manga is about food. Every customer was impressed by it.

Comment: No, not the one I'm looking for.